# What does signed 4-byte big-endian integer mean and how to form one in vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to create a gamespy v4 gameserver query tool. In first response I get ASCII represented number in bytes. I converted it to integer. Now I need to convert it to 4-byte big-endian integer and send it to the server. What does actually 4-byte big-endian integer mean and how I can form one? I'm using VB.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 4-byte Big-endian integer is an integer that is our bytes long with the most significant bit first.

One way to generate a 4 byte Big-endian integer is to use the `IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(int32)`. To do so:

```
IntegerAsBytes = IPAddress.HostoNetworkOrder(DirectCast(Integer,Int32))
```

Comment: "Using DirectCast operator to cast a value-type to the same type is obsolete". However the code is working fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: If your storing the integer in an Int32 or integer it is unnecessary but i wasn't sure if  you where using any of the other variants of integer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation

[Explanation of Big Endian and Little Endian Architecture](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102025)

```
    Dim test1 As Int32 = &H12345678

    Dim test2 As Integer

    test2 = Net.IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(test1)

    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:x}  {1:x}", test1, test2))
```